# Logitech MX Laser mouse authorization problem with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

My problem is: since upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I can't get my Bluetooth mouse to work anymore (it has an USB receiver). The devices are getting recognized, also my bluetooth is working. The outputs:

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 004: ID 046d:c70c Logitech, Inc. BT Mini-Receiver (HID proxy mode)
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 046d:c70b Logitech, Inc. BT Mini-Receiver (HID proxy mode)
Bus 006 Device 005: ID 046d:c709 Logitech, Inc. BT Mini-Receiver (HCI mode)
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:0b02 Logitech, Inc. C-UV35 [Bluetooth Mini-Receiver] (HID proxy mode)
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 413c:8140 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 360 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

hciconfig:

```
hci1:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:07:61:71:99:F9  ACL MTU: 1017:7  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING
    RX bytes:506 acl:0 sco:0 events:23 errors:0
    TX bytes:345 acl:0 sco:0 commands:23 errors:0

hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:1E:37:C2:AD:CA  ACL MTU: 310:10  SCO MTU: 64:8
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN
    RX bytes:1136 acl:0 sco:0 events:65 errors:0
    TX bytes:3888 acl:0 sco:0 commands:65 errors:0
```

What should I do to make it work? I've tried to register my mouse as trusty device, but it seems like the commands from earlier Ubuntu versions aren't working as they should. Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Please use the `{}` button instead of the `"` button to format output.

Comment: It looks like you have multiple bluetooth adapters connected via USB. Is that correct? Why?

Comment: @heynnema nope, it is a wireless mouse and an USB receiver that belong together

Comment: [just like here][https://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images500x500/Logitech_931571_0403_MX_610_Left_Hand_Laser_Cordless_436251.jpg]

Comment: @Chai T.Rex I can't edit my comments, sorry. An usual torture of the new forum members

Comment: According to the following page, my mouse devices has been correctly recognized: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-problem-notmoving.html The output I get is: {2: "Virtual core pointer" [XPointer]
4: "Virtual core XTEST pointer" [XExtensionPointer]
10: "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" [XExtensionPointer]
12: "Logitech Logitech BT Mini-Receiver" [XExtensionPointer]}

Comment: I have also paired the device successfully. But the mouse pointer cannot be moved with my wireless mouse. I have got one error notice: Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Input/output error

Comment: @tetakpatak I understand that one Logitech mouse and one Logitech USB receiver go together. Although you don't need 1 receiver per mouse, as each receiver can handle up to 6 mice/keyboards. My comment was referring to the output of your lsusb command. It shows multiple Logitech USB devices, and multiple bluetooth devices. No? If you have that many receivers, it's no wonder that your BT mouse gets confused.

Comment: @heynnema dear mate, only my (one single) mouse USB receiver was connected to the PC at that point. It is not the reason for my issue

Comment: Well, it's kind of disappointing that no one seems to know the answer. There is an update: now the mouse works just NEVER after booting into Ubuntu for the first time, but it finally works just ALWAYS after it was once on standby, closed without shutting down the system.